# Invalid Request in Api Request.php line 108: Must provide source or customer

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

i'm using stripe with laravel in my project , when i made payment its give me this error , stripe is not sending me the token that require for transaction 
Invalid Request in Api Request.php line 108: Must provide source or customer.

Answer (score 0):

All though this question could mean a lot I had this while using the test card on the stripe getting started page - 4242424242424242 - I made the mistake of creating the token on the site instead of allowing my .js script do the trick .

[dont create token on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hiqk.png)

Hence if youre trying to create the token dynamically like this -it would not work. In my case from a post handler.

Charge::create(
                array(
                  "amount" => $cart->totalPrice * 100 ,
                  "currency" => "usd",
                  "source" => $request->input('stripeToken') , //wont work
                  "description" => "Test Charge"
                ));

--To fix this I had to manually enter the token created on the site like so:

Charge::create(
                array(
                  "amount" => $cart->totalPrice * 100 ,
                  "currency" => "usd",
                  "source" => "tok_for-this-transaction-and-card" , //I made this change
                  "description" => "Test Charge"
                ));